# Swift JSON parsing with no particular structure

Tags: json, parsing

I have a JSON object of this type, very pratical do loop (for each key => value)
It's like JSON of JSON

But I'm not able to decode it in Swift.
I'm trying to know if this type of data is decodable in Swift.
If it would be easy for you, could you please help to decode it? In an array for example.

{"1":{"1":"some text"},"2":{"1":"some text","2":"some text","3":"some text","4":"some text"},"3":{"1":" some text","2":"some text","3":"some text"},"4":{"1":"some text","2":"some text"},"5":{"1":"some text"},"6":{"1":"some text","2":"some text","3":"some text"}}

```
        let jsonDict = json_text
        let jsonDictData = jsonDict.data(using: .utf8)!

        let object = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(
            with: jsonDictData,
            options: []
        )

        // Cast to a Swift Dictionary
        let dict = object as? [AnyHashable:Any]

        // Cast to an NSDictionary
        let nsDict = object as? NSDictionary
        print(nsDict)
```

it returns *nil*

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I parse it by myself.
With `.components(separatedBy: "},")`
and `.components(separatedBy: "\",\"")`

and sweeping some characters with `.replacingOccurrences(of: pattern, with: "")`
pattern id for example pattern = `"\"1\":\""`